# JQuery/AJAX script works but notice is still displayed?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm sending data to another php file and then data is retrieved on success to be displayed in a div. however when I load my data.php script notice is always displayed " Undefined index: status in.... " that line on code is $var = $_POST['status'];.

This is a re-post/edit because the script actually works now but I just don't understand why the notice is still being displayed?!?

```html
<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//daddy code
$ (document).ready(function() {

//mama code
$("button#postbutton").click(function() {

 var data = $("#formpost").serialize();


$.ajax({

type: "POST",

url: "data.php",

data: data,

success: function(data) {

$("#statustext").html(data);

}

});




});



});









</script>
</head>

<body>







<div id="global">

<form id="formpost" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false">

<textarea id="text1" name="status" ></textarea>


<button id="postbutton">POST</button>

<a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a>

</form>

<br/>
<br/>


<div id="allstatus">



<!-- SKELETON -->


<div id="wholestatus">


<div id="statuspic">
</div>


<div id="statusinfo">

<div id="statusname">JOnathan</div>
<div id="statustext"> </div>
<div id="statusoption"><button id="likestatus">LIKE</button></div>
<div id="statusoption"><button id="commentstatus">COMMENT</button></div>
<div id="statusoption"><button id="sharestatus">SHARE</button></div>
<div id="statusoption"><button id="statustime">TIME</button></div>






</div>




</div> 




<!-- SKELETON -->








</div>




</div>







</body>
```

MY DATA file data.php

```html
<?php



$var = $_POST['status'];

const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
const DB_USER = 'root';
const DB_PASS = '';
const DB_NAME = 'forum';
//connecting 

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {



}


$sql = "INSERT INTO `question`(id, question) VALUES ('', '{$var}')";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result) {

 
}
 else {

  echo "failed: " . $conn->error;
 }


echo  "{$var}" ;


?>
```

Comment: Obviously, you do not pass `status` variable in POST parameters in your AJAX. That's why it is undefined. Please use your browser's developer tools to see what is actually passed to server via AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php

const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
const DB_USER = 'root';
const DB_PASS = '';
const DB_NAME = 'forum';
//connecting 

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {

 }

if(isset($_POST['status']))
{
$var = $_POST['status'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `question`(id, question) VALUES ('', '{$var}')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result) {

    }
    else {

    echo "failed: " . $conn->error;
   }
echo  "{$var}" ;
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below line/check

```
$var = '';
if(isset($_POST['status'])){
  $var = $_POST['status'];
}
```

Comment: In my opinion not an answer to his question. He didn't ask for a solution but why it's still being displayed.

Comment: Hi please help if I use the isset function i get a  Notice: Undefined variable: var in C:\xampp\htdocs\deadline\data.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined variable: var in C:\xampp\htdocs\deadline\data.php on line 44. That is the data php file with the lines $var in it

Comment: add $var = ''; above that..updated answer for this..Please have a look.

Comment: Add line $var = ''; it will fix mentioned error..updated answer with this fix.